# Queue multiple jobs after current one in shell

Tags: bash, zsh

[On](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362237/queue-up-commands-while-one-command-is-being-executed) [previous](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132068/queue-a-task-in-a-running-shell) [questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/487955/how-to-plan-a-task-to-run-after-another-already-running-task-in-bash/488007) similar to mine, the proposed solutions are all involved suspending the current foreground task with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and then running `fg && ...` or `fg ; ...` (and maybe sending the old task to the background `bg` first, so that it can continue running while the new command is being typed).

At least for me this only works with a single queued command. When I try using this trick multiple times in a row, the middle commands are forgotten:

```
$ sleep 60 && echo test1

^Z
[1]  + 2336348 suspended  sleep 60

$ fg && echo test2
[1]  + 2336348 continued  sleep 60

^Z
[1]  + 2336348 suspended  sleep 60

$ fg && echo test3
[1]  + 2336348 continued  sleep 60

test3
```

Note how `test1` was never printed (though I could live with that, this is just because my initial command consisted of two and my `sleep 60` was fully executed, which is what I care about most). More importantly, note how `test2` was never printed. This was my second command and I believe it was never executed.

What I want is to enqueue another command that I just thought of (while other commands were running) so that it runs after the current command and after/before all other commands that I have enqueued before. The ordering of the commands ultimately doesn't matter, but they cannot run simultaneously (otherwise I could just open another shell and run them there) because they depend on some common state (file system or so).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a GNU/Linux system or have coreutils installed, use [flock(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/flock) (maybe using the executable/command itself as the lockfile):

```
% cat linger
echo -n $$; date +%s; sleep $1

% flock ./linger ./linger 8 &
[3] 5941
% 59421598557788

% flock ./linger ./linger 9 &
[4] 5945
% flock ./linger ./linger 11 &
[5] 5946
% 59471598557796
59501598557805

[3]   Done                    flock ./linger ./linger 8
[4]   Done                    flock ./linger ./linger 9
[5]   Done                    flock ./linger ./linger 11
```

---

What you're trying to do doesn't work, because for the shell stopping a command is like it immediately exiting with a non-zero (fail) status:

```
% sleep 10 || echo FAIL
^Z
[3]+  Stopped                 sleep 10
FAIL
% fg
sleep 10
% echo $?
0
```